# how to give the user a full permissions in linux redhat 5

Tags: linux, redhat

I have created the user "tungsten" now how do I give full permissions to the user 
in linux redhat 5

Comment: What do you mean with "full permissions"? Do you mean something like `root` access - i.e. the user can do everything on the machine? Or do you want to give the user full access rights to specific files or directories?

Answer (score 2):

As ThiefMater stated, the proper way is giving him sudo access, but if you wish to set full permissions for a certain user, edit /etc/passwd

You should have something like

```
 daniel:x:1000:100:WhateverUserNameYouUse,someMoreInfo:/home/daniel:/bin/bash
```

Change that 1000 and 100 for 0

```
 daniel:x:0:0:WhateverUserNameYouUse,someMoreInfo:/home/daniel:/bin/bash
```

But still, listen, the entire idea with a normal user account is to not have complete access to everything. If that's what you want, you can just as well log in as root directly. There are several reasons not to do that, though, among others that normal user software usually isn't as secure as what is normally required by root access, meaning that if someone hacks into a user utility, like gaim, over the internet when you're logged in as root, they can trash your entire system.
Why do you want to do this? Comment and maybe I'll can help you w/o doing this.

Comment: the intention of giving the root privileges are as follows:

Comment: Looks like you forgot to type the rest :P

Comment: i have created the user "tungsten" with the command (/usr/sbin/useradd tungsten). now i want the user to "tungsten" to allow any command to run

Comment: Ok homie, as I told you in the answer, edit /etc/passwd (with nano or kwrite gedit or whatever editor you want to use) and change the nrs appearing at the right of tungsten for 0 and 0 as in the answer I wrote...

Comment: # id tungsten
# usermod -u 0 tungsten
# id tungsten

Comment: #id will give you a gid, change that gid for # groupmod -g yourgid 0  and you would be done.

Answer (score 1):

If someone should have full permissions the proper way is giving him `sudo` access to the `root` user. Then he can use `sudo su -` to get a root shell.

Another solution would be giving the user the UID 0 which makes him a root user. However, usually it's good to have only one UID 0 user: root.

Comment: yes I want full permissions like root access

Comment: I told you what to do. You could also give the user the UID 0, but usually only root should have that...